# How can I write a default constructor for a 1x1 matrix with an ArrayList (in Java)?

Tags: java, matrix, arraylist

To be more clear, the 1x1 matrix needs to have a single false value. Each matrix row as being an object of type `ArrayList<Boolean>`. Then the overall matrix is an `ArrayList` of these objects. In other words, the matrix is an object of type `ArrayList<ArrayList<Boolean>>`.

Like in C it would be

```
 Container = new ArrayList()
 Container.add(new ArrayList<>)[arrayList<Boolean>()]
 Container[0].add($false)
```

or something like that. I'm just confused on how to write the constructor in Java that would be the sort of same thing.

Comment: There are no constructors and no `new` keyword in C.

Comment: why did you tag this question to c ?

Comment: Since when C supports `Bool` data type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a `nRows x nCols` matrix:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Boolean>> matrix = new ArrayList<>(nRows);
for(int r = 0 ; r < nRows ; r++) {
    ArrayList<Boolean> row = new ArrayList<>(nCols);
    for(int c = 0 ; c < nCols ; c++) {
        row.add(false);
    }
    matrix.add(row);
}
```

For a `1 x 1`:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Boolean>> matrix = new ArrayList<>(1);
ArrayList<Boolean> row = new ArrayList<>(1);
row.add(false);
matrix.add(row);
```

Answer (score 2):

This will create an n x n matrix:

```
    ArrayList<ArrayList<boolean>> matrix = new ArrayList<ArrayList<boolean>>(n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        ArrayList<boolean> row = new ArrayList<boolean>(n);
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
           row.add(false);
        }
        lists.add(row);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

An example Matrix class with n x m constructor:

```
public class Matrix extends ArrayList<ArrayList<Boolean>> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Matrix(int rowNum, int colNum) {
        super(rowNum);

        for (int row=0; row<rowNum; row++) {
            ArrayList<Boolean> rowList = new ArrayList<Boolean>(colNum);
            add(rowList);
            for (int col=0; col<colNum; col++) {
                rowList.add(false);
            }
        }
    }

    public void set(int row, int col, Boolean value) {
        get(row).set(col, value);
    }

    public Boolean get(int row, int col) {
        return get(row).get(col);
    }

}
```

Comment: You do not need to check the bounds, just let the ``get`` from the ``ArrayList`` throw the ``ArrayOutOfBoundException``

Comment: @Jean Logeart: removed.